# I am unable to access my HTTP NGINX server over LAN

Tags: networking, firewall, nginx, webserver, ufw

I have allowed the port in `ufw` and have the following configuration:

```
server {
     listen 0.0.0.0:8000 default_server;
     server_name _;
     index index.html;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/html.access_log main;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/html.error_log info;
     root /var/www/html/htdocs;
}
```

I have tried basically every solution I found online. I have already set the server_name to `_` to allow access from everywhere, added `default_server` to the listen option, so NGINX will automatically use this entry. I can access it from my own machine.

Just to mention this issue has been happening ever since I started making my own webservers. Back then I was using `lighttpd` and the same problem occured. That's what made me switch to NGINX, but then the same problem happened with it as well. I somehow fixed it after that (I was working on my HTTPS server at the time and it got fixed by itself). This issue persisted across different installations of Gentoo as well. It doesn't seem like it's common at all. Knowing this, the solution might actually be my router, but its configuration is perfectly fine. Might it be the router firmware in any way?

Edit: I forgot to mention, I can access my SSH server only through my subdomain (thepowerofvfx.us.to). Accessing it using my local IP doesn't work. It returns "No route to host". Also it's pretty random. I can access my server sometimes, and sometimes I can't. I used to be able to use my SSH server through LAN before, but I can't now. I am using a static local IP. Might that be the cause?

Comment: "_It returns "No route to host"_" - you're going to g need to provide details. For example what is your client's IP address and what address are you trying to reach? How are you trying to access your website (a) externally (b) internally?

Comment: @ChrisDavies My client's IP address is 192.168.0.103. My server is at 192.168.0.108. I am accessing my server through LAN (my guess is that means internally).

Comment: Please add the information to your question. There is no need for "edit" statements, just (re) write your question as if you'd told us this in the beginning. Make the question straightforward to read

Comment: This question has so much text, but very little information about the problem. Check logfiles, include relevant snippets from them. Inlcude the commands you're running to access the webserver, and the exact error messages. Try accessing the webserver via loopback, does that work?